# Help, I tried to change the login screen background in 18.04 and now i cant get to the login screen to input password

Tags: 18.04, login, text, editor

I tried to change login screen background from standard to a picture I downloaded and now I am stuck, I cant get to the login screen.

All is a list and lots of 'ok' after it and then the screen goes blank.

Here is the instruction I followed. [LINK](https://vitux.com/how-to-change-login-lock-screen-background-in-ubuntu/)

CAN I Undo my mistake?

Here is what I thought I did successfully;

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

Edited Content:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///[fileLocation/filename.png]); (I put my own picture in here) 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107561/discussion-on-question-by-bigalxxx-help-i-tried-to-change-the-login-screen-back).

Comment: Have you tried to reset Gnome settings to default? Of course, if you can't login, you have to do it by the recovery mode in GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing ubuntu again from wherever you can install it. It will work. And be aware you will lose the applications and the files; it will be set to the things you had when you installed ubuntu. In other words everything will be set to default. EVERYTHING. And that is why it tells not to edit the files. Try following [this](https://vitux.com/how-to-change-login-lock-screen-background-in-ubuntu/) link on another computer and see the results. If that works then there must be something not working in the original computer.